# How to convert from POSIXct, POSIXt to numeric

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, purrr, readxl

I am getting Column **`First Commit Date` can't be converted from POSIXct, POSIXt to numeric
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)** error  when I run my R code. This is what I did.

```
all_data <- map_df(one_new, 
                   ~.x %>% 
                     excel_sheets() %>% 
                     map_df(read_excel, path = .x))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the format of dates in your `First Commit Date` column?

Comment: You could try specifying `read_excel(col_types = c("guess", "guess", "numeric", "guess"))`, putting the "numeric" in whichever position your date column is. In my example, it would read column C as numeric.

Comment: First Commit Date format - 
5/9/2018 12:00:00 AM

And there are like 900+ columns. so defining read_excel(col_types = c("guess", "guess", "numeric", "guess")) like this is practical?  @AllanCameron

Comment: I didn't know there were 900 columns @Sid, since you didn't specify that, or include any data in your question, and I couldn't have guessed that you had an unusually large amount of columns from your question. However, you could do `colformats <- rep("guess", 900)` then `colformats[3] <- "numeric"` then pass `col_types = colformats` to `read_excel`